# MFMailComposeViewController navigation bar not show some time

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have a share functionality in my app.when I open the MFMailComposeViewController for send email.Then sometimes it hides the navigation bar.Because in my app I have used custom navigation bar.So I have to hide the navigation controller on all screens.But when email pop up appears then I have unhide the navigation controller for show send or cancel button.But it does not appear sometime.Below is my code.Please tell me what I have done wrong in my code.I have tried all methods but I have unable to replicate this issue.

```
if ( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail())
                {
                    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=false
                    print("Can send email.")
                    let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
                    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
                    mailComposer.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
                    mailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
                    mailComposer.isNavigationBarHidden=false
                    mailComposer.navigationBar.isHidden=false
                    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
                    mailComposer.setSubject("")
                    mailComposer.setMessageBody(myHTMLString, isHTML: true)
                    //   mailComposer.setToRecipients([to_Email_Id])


                    self.present(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: {
                        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=false
                        mailComposer.isNavigationBarHidden=false
                        mailComposer.navigationBar.isHidden=false
                        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
                    })
                }
```

Comment: why are you presenting the mailComposer twice?

Comment: By mistake, it writes two times.

Comment: @GauravGupta You should not customize the appearance of Mail Compose.

Comment: @Mannopson I do not customize it. I only change the tint color.